# How do I background a systemd-nspawn container?

Tags: background-process, systemd-nspawn

I use `systemd-nspawn` to run a few containers. I can have them started in the background using `systemctl start systemd-nspawn@foo`. On occasion, however, I start with `systemd-nspawn -bD foo`. I couldn't find any way to send it to the background. Closing the terminal just kills the container as `machinectl list` shows. Can I do so, and if so, how?

I understand a container is much more than a single process, but in this sense, the expected effect is the same as backgrounding a process - I want the container running, but my original shell given back to me.

Comment: @mikeserv `machinectl kill -sTSTP foo` seems to have no discernable effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, for what it's worth, the following was successful for me:

```sh
sudo systemd-nspawn -bxD/
```

Practically identical to yours, except I don't give the *`machine`* a name and I get an `-x` ephemeral btrfs snapshot of my `/` for the container's root.

That brought up the container's `getty` on my terminal's pty and I logged in to `login` and all.

I confess I was a bit stumped for a little while, but after a little poking at `systemctl` in the container w/ `zsh` <tab> completion I came up with *(run from within the container)*:

```sh
systemctl stop console-getty.service
```

---

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or other units.
Authenticating as: mikeserv
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

Which got the machine to surrender its terminal control. The only thing is, I started that with `sudo` - which also gets its own layer of terminal control to authenticate in the first place. This left me with a blank terminal, and no amount of `kill -CONT "$(pgrep ksh)"` was doing me any good. And so I was again stumped for a moment or two, but *(in another terminal)*...

```sh
sudo fuser -v /dev/pts/*
```

---

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/pts/0:          mikeserv   8347 F.... zsh
                     root      18003 F.... sudo
/dev/pts/13:         mikeserv   9553 F.... zsh
                     mikeserv  16838 F.... ksh
                     root      17657 F.... sudo
                     root      17658 F.... systemd-nspawn
/dev/pts/14:         root      17675 F.... systemd
```

Gave me the above list, and so I thought - what the hell?

```sh
sudo kill -STOP 17657
```

And - lo and behold - I had `ksh` back in the original terminal. To wrap it up, I needed to verify I could still access the *`machine`*, though, of course, else it would be useless:

```sh
machinectl -l
```

---

```
MACHINE                    CLASS     SERVICE
localhost-35ceaa76b1306897 container nspawn
```

Ok...

```sh
sudo machinectl login localhost-35ceaa76b1306897
```

---

```
Connected to machine localhost-35ceaa76b1306897. 
Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.

Arch Linux 4.0.7-2-ARCH (pts/0)

localhost-35ceaa76b1306897 login:
```

And I got another `getty` on another terminal!

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. My approach is to use `dtach` to control attaching and detaching from the terminal that is running the container. Then inside the container I can run `tmux` / `screen` etc.

`machinectl` will allow you to run containers at boot, but as of this writing, debian stable does not have a version of `systemd` that includes this feature.